# Does Origen understand ATE specifications like measurement accuracy?

Tags: origen-sdk

I see that Origen allows users to [model specifications](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/specs/) and wondered if there were any built-in specifications for ATE hardware? For example, the measurement accuracy of the pin electronics card?  Having this modeled in one spot seems like an overall benefit for the Origen community when trying to set ATE parameters for [Origen testers](http://origen-sdk.org/testers/).

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people in NXP were working on enhancements like that, but the team got disbanded for business reasons and the work got dropped.

I think it is a good idea, and OrigenTesters probably already has some of it built in, but it is not really complete or documented anywhere.

Here is a video showing some of it in action if you want to resurrect it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPRlygf162k&t=